# How to upload images to amazon s3 server , I have the secret key, Accesskey and bucket name in iOS using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here I have  secret key, Accesskey and bucket name these credentials are enough to store and get the images from amazon s3 server or need any other? And I installed cocoapods with following link:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup-aws-sdk-for-ios.html

The problem I faced is unable to move my work forward please provide any step by step process to succeed?

Comment: check on this links:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/12841587/4831524 or 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/12841587/4831524

Answer (score 0):

You can refer documentation for [Amazon S3 Transfer Manager for iOS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html) its contain all the information for integration of SDK with how to upload and download image from S3 storage.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager;

-(void)uploadImage:(UIImage*)img
{
    NSString *bucketName = @"bucket_Name";
    NSString *fileName = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""] stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    fileName = [@"ios" stringByAppendingString:fileName];
    NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:fileName];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    NSUInteger size = imageData.length;
    [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    uploadRequest.bucket = bucketName;
    uploadRequest.key = fileName;
    uploadRequest.contentType = @"image/png";
    uploadRequest.body = url;
    uploadRequest.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:size];

    uploadRequest.uploadProgress = ^(int64_t bytesSent, int64_t totalBytesSent, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (totalBytesExpectedToSend > 0) {

                weakself.file_size = totalBytesExpectedToSend;
                weakself.file_uploaded = totalBytesSent;

                [weakself updateProgress];
            }
        });
    };

    [[_transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock: ^id(AWSTask *task){
        if (task.error)
        {
            NSLog(@"ERROR : %@",task.error);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Uploaded on : \n https://s3_path_for.amazonaws.com/%@/%@", bucketName, fileName);
            UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uploaded :)"
                                                                  message:@""
                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles: nil];
        }
        return nil;
    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks for code but block of code is not executing bro

Comment: Where did you stuck ? You have to set your bucket_Name and  https://s3_path_for.amazonaws.com to work this code. I am using same code to store chat images on s3.

Comment: or you can follow steps from [Amazon S3 Transfer Manager for iOS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html).